# WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable on mac

Tags: hadoop

I'm using Mac OSX El-Capitan, and new to hadoop. After installation I'm getting this warning:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-rippermode-namenode-Nitin-Pro.mshome.net.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-rippermode-datanode-Nitin-Pro.mshome.net.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-rippermode-secondarynamenode-Nitin-Pro.mshome.net.out
16/12/07 15:16:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/yarn-rippermode-resourcemanager-Nitin-Pro.mshome.net.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/yarn-rippermode-nodemanager-Nitin-Pro.mshome.net.out
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to compile hadoop yourself in order to solve this issue.

The problem is not all hadoop is written in java. There are a couple of native libraries that come with hadoop and that depend on other libraries in the OS. Some of that dependencies are not met because hadoop you've downloaded was built on a different system.

Comment: thanks.. but i have never done that before, can you tell me how to proceed ?

Comment: These instructions are for RHEL 7, but you can find them useful: https://github.com/hadoopfromscratch/hadoopfromscratch. Before you can build hadoop, you'll need to install java, maven, gcc and some libraries (zlib, snappy, protobuf). Once it is done, the build process is pretty straightforward: mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar